# How to blur out an entire webpage when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm setting up a one-page website with react.js, html, and scss.  I am struggling to have the entire website have a blur effect or fade when a button is clicked (this will be later used for loading animations).  What commands can I use to get this blur when a button is pressed?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="top-bar">
          <div className="title">poem</div>
          <img className="logo" src="./logo.png" />
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="sloganLineOne">Poem Theme</div>
          <div className="sloganLineTwo">Detector</div>
          <textarea
            className="inputField"
            placeholder="Please Enter Your Poem Here..."
          />
          <button className="button" onClick={this.fadeOut}>
            Enter
          </button>
          <img className="leftTriangle" src="./leftSideTriangle.png" />
          <img className="rightTriangle" src="./rightSideTriangle.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  fadeOut = () => this.setState({ fadingOut: true })
}
```

I expect the entire page to be blurred or look like it when the button is clicked.

Comment: you can blur in `css`. Something like `body { filter: blur(2px); }` In your use case probably do an inline style on the app div? `<div className="App" style={this.state.fadingOut ? {filter: 'blur(2px)'} : undefined }>`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm not exactly sure how that can be done with the button click, and I'm not sure how to do the button click

Comment: What is unsure? you are setting state, that updates the render. what i posted is how you would use that state to apply the blur. If you need me to write it up as an answer i can do that :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell If you don't mind, I would appreciate it if you wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is apply the style to your parent div and you should be good to go! Give this a shot

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { fadingOut: false }

  fadeOut = () => this.setState({fadingOut: true});

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={this.state.fadingOut ? {filter: 'blur(2px)'} : undefined }> 
        <div className="top-bar">
          <div className="title">
              poem
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="sloganLineOne">Poem Theme</div>
          <div className="sloganLineTwo">Detector</div>
          <textarea className="inputField" placeholder="Please Enter 
Your Poem Here..."></textarea>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.fadeOut}>Enter</button>
          <img className="leftTriangle" src="./leftSideTriangle.png"/>
          <img className="rightTriangle" src="./rightSideTriangle.png"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}
```

[See it in action!](https://jsfiddle.net/3k9jnsgf/1/)